# Auto insert Admob ID to project

Tags: android-studio

I just want to get the knowledge about insert Admob ID.

During coding, we have to use Admob ID Sample. When ready to build project, at that time insert real ID. If project have many Activity and many xml file, we need to insert many time. And when we edit project, we have to insert again sample ID.

In that case, we need a lot of time so I would like to ask, have any way to do it fast and safety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this line to string.xml located in res->values folder

```
<string name="admob_id">PASTE_YOUR_ADMOB_ID_HERE</string>
```

you just need to write admob_id where you require your id it.

Comment: Thanks Navjyot Singh, that is just for java file. How about xml file?

Comment: you need to call @string/admob_id in your xml